# SocketException thrown when stopping my TCP Server java

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp

Im getting this error when closing my TCP Server from my form.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at com.hightekjonathan.HomeServer.Server.Start(Server.java:36)
    at com.hightekjonathan.HomeServer.Form$2.run(Form.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Heres the Server.java:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Server {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    private static DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    private static int port = 19586;

    private static boolean running = false;

    public void Start() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting Server...");

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            System.out.println("Server Started");
            System.out.println("IP Address: " + getIpAddress());
            System.out.println("Listening: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

            running = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to connect to clients...");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if (running) {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (serverSocket != null) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            running = false;
        }
    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}
```

Its started on a new thread from my GUI Form using this function:

```
button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         buttonActionPerformed(evt);
    }
);
```

And then `buttonActionPerformed()` is this:

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!server.isRunning()) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                server.Start();
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();

        button.setText("Stop Server");
        serverStatus.setText("Server: Started");
    } else {
        server.Stop();

        button.setText("Start Server");
        serverStatus.setText("Server: Stopped");
    }
}
```

The error only appears when I stop the server when no clients have connected. But when a client connects, then disconnects, I don't get that error. It properly closes it, I just want to make sure that error won't be a serious problem, or if there is an easy way of fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your server, you call serverSocket.accept(). This call blocks thread until a connection is made. And by calling server.stop() you are closing this server socket in another thread. ServerSocket.close() JavaDoc says: 
`Any thread currently blocked in {@link #accept()} will throw a {@link SocketException}.`

So thats why you are getting this exception.

I think you can just ignore this exception.

P.S.
And you should make your `boolean running` volatile.

Comment: Yeah - just dump the exception.

Comment: So it should be safe to ignore?

Comment: @pomkine so set the bool to this `private static volatile boolean running = false;`? or set it to volatile when retrieving it?

Comment: @hightekjonathan just make it volatile : private static volatile boolean running = false; Yes, it should be safe in this situation

Comment: @pomkine Alright, thanks. What exactly does changing it to volatile do?

Comment: @hightekjonathan you are using 2 thread here. Without volatile the thread checking running state can see stale data. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html for more info.